# What does this python2 error mean, and what should I do about it?

Tags: arch-linux, python

Whenever I attempt to use an application relating to python2(gnome-tweak-tool, bzr, etc.) it fails to start and, when run from command-line, I get this error:

```
    [username@host ~]$ gnome-tweak-tool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 520, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 419, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 287, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/bin/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

I had posted this on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105226/what-does-this-python2-error-mean-and-what-should-i-do-about-it#comment122345_105226), but was told it belonged here, since I use Arch Linux.
Output for python2:

```
    [username@host ~]$ python2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 520, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 419, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 287, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/bin/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Strange. Take a look yourself at the output of `pacman -Ql python2` and can you post the output of `whereis python2`? Try `pacman -Rs python` and then `pacman -Syyu python`. Maybe you out of sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your Python install is messed up: `/usr/bin/lib/python2.7/...` makes no sense since Python installs its stuff under `/usr/lib/python2.7`

Try removing the python package and then reinstalling it again.

Comment: I already tried `sudo pacman -Rdd python2; sudo pacman -S python2 ` multiple times.

Comment: Rather strange, then... I don't understand where Python is getting this `/usr/bin/lib` path from.

Comment: did a `sudo mv /usr/bin/lib/python2.7 /usr/bin/lib/python2.7.old` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu, I was able to get this to work with

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7

export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.7

sudo ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib/python2.7/lib

sudo ln -s /usr /usr/lib/python2.7/local
```

There's probably an error in sysconfig.py where it's appending an absolute path on top of another absolute path (ignoring actual system paths and settings), rather than a relpath on top of an abspath